# Database vs tablespace, what's the difference?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In oracle  what's the differences between a database and a table space?

Comment: @mishik - tablespaces contain objects which occupy disk space, such as tables and indexes.  See SimonK's answer below.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A little terminology:

Oracle defines a **database** as the set of files that you find on your Oracle system. This means all data in your Oracle system is in these database files, commonly known as "data files". There are other files in the database such as parameter files and redo logs.

On the other hand, an **instance** consists of the processes and memory areas that Oracle database uses. Together, a **database** and an **instance** make up a **database system**. ([For more information, see the Oracle Concept guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/startup.htm#CNCPT601))

Logically, you will want to define different spaces within that database. This is done via **tablespaces** (see [Oracle Concept guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT402)). A tablespace usually consists of one or more data files. When you define a table with CREATE TABLE, you can specify in which tablespace the table should be created. This allows you to seperate different applications on the same database system, for example.

The Oracle Concepts guide is an excellent source of information for questions like these. [See this picture](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT301) on how data files and tablespaces are composed.

Comment: In sql server you create databases, in oracle you create tablespaces? Then what's scheme? It's the same as sql server schema?

Comment: Oh, SQL Servers terminology differs from Oracles terminology. In Oracle, you have one or more **instances** accessing one **database** with multiple **schemas**. A database can have multiple **tablespaces** where schemas can save data. Note that often, "schemas" and "users" are used as synonyms in Oracle. In SQL Server, you often have multiple databases with multiple schemas within a single database server.

Comment: I'm a little confused, so if i have to two difference applications, I would create a new instance for each application or new tablespace for each application or new database per application? (In SQL Server, you can just create a new database)

Comment: Note that the above link to the Oracle Concept guide is broken. Perhaps this is the correct link? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/toc.htm

Comment: @SimonKrenger your links are not working and you didn't talk about why multiple table space is needed?

Comment: @SimonK. If you can give more details on this, I am reiterating the Kanagavelu's question - why should I need mltiple tablespaces ?

Answer (score 6):

Let's consider an example of an Ocean consist of lots of water. Now you want that water. For this what you do is collect water in barrel for better usage and better storage purpose. Same here **Ocean is database** having lots of Data files here **data file means water** and for better usage and handling you put that into barrel you can relate **barrel as Tablespace**

> An Oracle database consists of one or more logical storage units
>   called tablespaces, which collectively store all of the database's
>   data.

Databases, tablespaces, and datafiles are closely related, but they have important differences:

> Each tablespace in an Oracle database consists of one or more files
>   called datafiles, which are physical structures that conform to the
>   operating system in which Oracle is running.
>
> A database's data is collectively stored in the datafiles that
>   constitute each tablespace of the database. For example, the simplest
>   Oracle database would have one tablespace and one datafile. Another
>   database can have three tablespaces, each consisting of two datafiles
>   (for a total of six datafiles).

[image]

[reference link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm)

Comment: love the "ocean water" analogy!

Answer (score 4):

DATABASES's data are stored in logical storage units called TABLESPACES. A database may contain "one or more" tablespaces. A tablespace may contain one or more datafiles.

A database's data is collectively stored in the datafiles that constitute each tablespace of the database.

Example: the simplest database may have one tablespace and one datafile. On the other hande another database can have 5 tablespaces which may contain two datafiles each (On a total of 10 files)

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite dated. IBM Db2 also has Table spaces. I think there is some commonality between Db2 table spaces and Oracle database table spaces. In that respect [this link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=databases-table-spaces) offers more insight into why table spaces, as storage structures, are needed and how are they distinct from databases. Two benefits are easy recoverability of the database and better storage management.