# New Database vs new tablespace vs new instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, db2, database-connection

I have an database instance in it there is one database and two tablespace for two different java web applications. Now we have to implement for new java web application so what is the best way to do this. Should we create a new instance,new database ,a new table space..pls suggest. I have less idea about storage so please explain me from basics. Thanks,

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or DB2? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle defines a **database** as the set of files that you find on your Oracle system. This means all data in your Oracle system is in these database files, commonly known as "data files".

On the other hand, an **instance** consists of the processes and memory areas that Oracle database uses.

Logically, you will want to define different spaces within that database. This is done via **tablespaces**. A tablespace usually consists of one or more data files. When you define a table with CREATE TABLE, you can specify in which tablespace the table should be created.

Please find the below link for more details:
[Database vs tablespace, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409862/database-vs-tablespace-whats-the-difference)

Comment: So if i have multiple applications i should not create a new database or there are cases when i need to create..is the any performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on

- independence of the applications
- independence of the data
- indepencence of the maintenance

If the applications should not depend at all and you need to bring them on another fixpack or DB2 version independend of each other separate instances solve your problem.

If you want to separate them onto different servers in future i.e. because of completely different performance characteristics - separate databases would be good. Separate DBs allow you to configure the database (buffers etc.) and to specify backup/high availability secenarios as needed for the different applications.

Having everthing in a single DB - with maybe different tablespaces will limit your options regarding above topics but will provide the easiest way to work with the common data.